# How can I generate a query string out of an associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a module wherein I need to pass data obtained by select query (in form [Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )] into a URL and then to get it on the page. I looked around for example but couldn't find one. Right now my query string looks like

```
allow_revalidity.php?moduleId=<?php echo $moduleid; ?>
```

where my $moduleid prints  `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )`. I want to extract 1 and 3 on allow_revalidity.php and to form a meaningful query string for the same. How can it be achieved. I have tried http_build_query and it gives string as 
`allow_revalidity.php?moduleId=0=1&1=3`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NigelRen I went through this. Couldn't find much help. May I know a solution for this. Thanks for the concern mate

Comment: D'oh! Sorry - should read it properly next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use implode, just setting the glue to be something useful...

```
echo "allow_revalidity.php?moduleId[]=".implode("&moduleId[]=",$moduleid);
```

Produces...

```
allow_revalidity.php?moduleId[]=1&moduleId[]=3
```

In the called page, just access `$_GET["moduleId"]` which should have

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how to retrieve this on next page??

Comment: Updated with how to access the data in target page.

Answer (score 0):

Also using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), you could also do:

`$url = 'allow_revalidity.php?moduleId=' . implode(',',$moduleid);`

which would generate `allow_revalidity.php?moduleId=1,3`.

On the called page, you just retrieve it via `split(',', $_GET['moduleId'])`.

Just a personal preference :)